# iOS SQLite3 database is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

1. I've got a JSON file which contains more than 2000 arrays, and in each array there may have an array with 5 strings.
2. I'm running two for() loops in one function, so I think the 2ed one will be run after the 1st one is done?

   and it sometimes appears the following(random data error appear):

   > database is locked

   when I'm executing

   ```
   INSERT INTO problemTags(problem_IDIndex)VALUES('93E')
   ```

---

And I use the code below to execute my SQL statement

```
+ (void)execSqliteWithSQL:(NSString *)sql{
    sqlite3 *sqlite = nil;
    int openResult = sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &sqlite);
    if(openResult != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"open DB error");
    }
    char *error;
    int execResult = sqlite3_exec(sqlite, [sql UTF8String], nil, nil, &error);
    if(execResult != SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n execResult error=>\n %s \n SQL:\n%@\n",error,sql];
        NSLog(@"%@",errorString);
    }
    sqlite3_close(sqlite);
}
```

---

I'm thinking about the reason to this issue is that
when I'm running the `for` loop, it sends several SQL statement to the `execSqliteWithSQL` function and when it can't run fast enough the data base would be closed?

---

question added below:

**without using threads**
the two for loops is like below:

```
-(void)......{
    for(){
       //sending SQL to execSqliteWithSQL
    }

    for(){
       //sending SQL to execSqliteWithSQL
    }

 }
```

Comment: First thought is that database runs on a different thread and you are opening and closing on each write.  Open the database, do your for loops and then close your database - pass a boolean return from that function so you can break the loop and close on error.  Not only will it be faster but there is a good chance currently your close is still finishing when you try to open hence your error.

Comment: Two possibilities:  1) you are doing concurrent ops on the DB (don't).  2) you failed to properly close/clean up a prior operation.

Comment: the two for loops are running in one function without threads, so I don't know why SQL-exec would occur at the same time? if the SQLite received several query would the query lined up ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Do you possibly have multiple threads calling this `execSqliteWithSQL` concurrently? If so, errors like this are very likely.

   You could remedy this by setting up a dedicated serial queue to which `execSqliteWithSQL` would dispatch its calls, thus eliminating attempts to do this concurrently.
2. Regardless, I would advise against opening and closing the database for each call. That's horribly inefficient.

   In fact, if doing a bunch of update/insert statements, you not only don't want to open and close the database for every call, but rather you want to open, call `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, do your updates, and then `COMMIT` those changes. The performance difference is startling.
3. This `execSqliteWithSQL` clearly presupposes that you're manually building your SQL (presumably with `stringWithFormat`). That's problematic at best, dangerous at worst. If a quotation mark appears in a string value being inserted into the database, the SQL will fail. If this feed includes any user input, you are susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

   Instead, you should use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to prepare a SQL statement with `?` placeholders, and then use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind values to those placeholders.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob,
I'm sure I haven't been using threads, and still don't know why this happened.
I'll recode my function according to you suggestion.
as a beginner of iOS development, your answer help me a lot :D

Comment: Rob I also find a library called FMDB, I think it's much better for controlling Database.  when I'm using [db executeUpdate:sql] it also fixed the SQL Injection issue :D

Comment: No, just using `executeUpdate` with SQL that you built manually does _not_ solve the SQL injection problem. You have to use `?` placeholders in your SQL, and then add the values as parameters to `executeUpdate`. But I'm a big fan of FMDB and encourage you to use it, as it makes your life _much_ easier.

Comment: started trying FMDB for a few hours, this is really a cool tool!!